# After making a large edit to a question, how to make sure it pops up on people's radar?

Tags: support

I'm struggling to get a response [for my question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/23801/issues-with-the-smoothing-operator-in-coherence-estimation-using-the-complex-mor) and I made a lot of edits to it to make it appeal to a larger audience (added figure, code examples, better structuring, headlines, etc.)

Yet I have the feeling that these edits don't really get propagated to e.g. follower of the tags, that they got notified only when the question first appeared. If I were more desperate, I'd create a new question, but that's quite close to spamming.

My reputation isn't high enough to set a bounty, so I'm looking at different ways to get attention.